# How can I automatically shut down an Azure VM?

Tags: windows, shell, azure

I want to create an Azure Virtual Machine that I only need to run approximately for 1 or 2 hours once or twice per day.  I don't want to pay for the server when I'm not using it.

I know I can just go to the dashboard and shut it off, but I often forget to do so, I'm getting senile!  I would like for a timer to start when the system (Windows 10) is started, and when the timer reaches zero, the image is made inactive (no charges incurred) unless I request more time.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The dashboard has an automatic shutdown feature. This can also be configured to send a webhook [notification](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-devtest-labs-auto-shutdown-notification/) with a link which will delay the shutdown. Currently in-machine notifications [are not supported](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/320373-devtest-labs/suggestions/19749871-auto-shutdown-warning).

[image: Azure VM Autoshutdown]

Although there are many tools like PowerShell scripts and apps that you could use from within the VM to trigger automatic shutdown, there are some [billing gotchas](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/windows/) to be aware of.

With an Azure VM, you pay per second and cease paying only when the machine is completely deallocated and no longer reserving memory and cores on the platform. (There is still a nominal storage charge associated with storage of the VM image). You cannot deallocate the VM from within itself.

To ensure the VM isn't incurring charges, check that the status is 'Stopped (deallocated').

Comment: Thanks, it looks like what I want to do is impossible.